# Incorrect syntax near '/'

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net

```
cmSQL = New SqlCommand("UPDATE AdBanner SET AdBannerTitle='" & txTitle.Text & "',AdBannerFileUrl=/Images/'" & fileUpload.FileName & "',AdBannerTargerUrl='" & txTargetUrl.Text & "',AdBannerIsActive='" & chkBox.Checked & "' WHERE AdBannerID='" & lblBannerId.Text & "'", cnSQL)
```

Error:Incorrect syntax near '/'.

i got that error when  updating record

Comment: use parameters(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) instead of concat, take a look sql injection(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: [Thou shalt not inject!](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must put the quotation mark (`'`) before `/Images/`. Change your statement to this:

```
cmSQL = New SqlCommand("UPDATE AdBanner SET AdBannerTitle='" & txTitle.Text _
        & "',AdBannerFileUrl='/Images/" & fileUpload.FileName _
        & "',AdBannerTargerUrl='" & txTargetUrl.Text _
        & "',AdBannerIsActive='" & chkBox.Checked _
        & "' WHERE AdBannerID='" & lblBannerId.Text & "'", cnSQL)
```

And when you're done with that, I'd recommend you start learning about [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) immediately. It's a simple but dangerous security hazard.

Comment: Personally, I would try avoiding SQL injection.

Comment: @UweKeim yes, I'm about to add that to the answer

Answer (score 2):

The *immediate* problem is that you aren't creating a valid literal for `AdBannerFileUrl`; however! Your approach at the moment is **deadly**. Please see "SQL injection". You should parameterize that, then it becomes:

```
cmSql = new SqlCommand("UPDATE AdBanner SET AdBannerTitle=@Title,AdBannerFileUrl=@FileUrl,AdBannerTargerUrl=@TargetUrl,AdBannerIsActive=@IsActive WHERE AdBannerID=@ID", cnSQL)
```

However! You must then add parameters for each of those:

```
cmSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", txtTitle.Text);
cmSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileUrl", "/Images/" + fileUpload.FileName);
cmSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TargetUrl", txTargetUrl.Text);
cmSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsActive", chkBox.Checked);
cmSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", lblBannerId.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `'` before the `/Images/` part, so the SQL that SQL Server gets is malformed.

However, doing a concatenation based SQL on the server, in this day and age, is, to put it bluntly, stupid, especially when using unvalidated user-suplied values (like txTitle.Text)

A better approach would be:

```
cmSQL = New SqlCommand("UPDATE AdBanner SET AdBannerTitle=@AdBannerTitle" _
    & ", AdBannerFileUrl=@AdBannerFileUrl" _
    & ", AdBannerTargerUrl=@AdBannerTargerUrl" _
    & ", AdBannerIsActive=@AdBannerIsActive" _
    & " WHERE AdBannerID=@AdBannerID", cnSQL)
cmSQL.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

cmSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdBannerTitle", txTitle.Text)
cmSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdBannerFileUrl", "/Images/" & fileUpload.FileName)
cmSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdBannerTargerUrl", txTargetUrl.Text)
cmSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdBannerIsActive", chkBox.Checked)
cmSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdBannerID", lblBannerId.Text)
```

Answer (score 0):

your single quotes are misplaced.

your code must be

```
    cmSQL = New SqlCommand("UPDATE AdBanner SET AdBannerTitle='" & txTitle.Text & "',AdBannerFileUrl='/Images/" & fileUpload.FileName & "',AdBannerTargerUrl='" & txTargetUrl.Text & "',AdBannerIsActive='" & chkBox.Checked & "' WHERE AdBannerID='" & lblBannerId.Text & "'", cnSQL)
```